VS Code IntelliSense Loading Indefinitely Across All Projects on macOS Sonoma for TypeScript/NextJs
I'm experiencing an issue with Visual Studio Code where IntelliSense is stuck on "Loading" indefinitely across all my TypeScript/NextJs projects. Whenever I Clicked ^ + space, I only see "Loading..." and don't get any suggestions or error messages even the code does not detect the Errors.
Images Here...
Loading Status ,
Whenever Typed or Clicked ^ + space 
Additional Information:

OS: macOS Sonoma v14.5
VS Code Version: 1.90.2
Extensions Installed:

ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets
GitLens — Git supercharged
Nextjs snippets
Prettier - Code formatter
Tailwind CSS IntelliSense
Console Ninja
Turbo Console Log
Atom One Dark Theme
Better Comments


Language/Framework Used: TypeScript ^5 with Next.js

Here are the steps I've already tried to resolve the issue:

Disabling all extensions.
Reinstalling all extensions.
Reinstalling VS Code.
Clearing the IntelliSense cache.
Updating VS Code to the latest version.
Restarting my machine.

None of these steps have resolved the issue, and I'm still facing the same problem. Has anyone encountered this issue before and found a solution? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ok, this is what fixed it for me: remove the project folder, and clone the repo again. Why it works, I do not know.
We tested it with no react projects, and it seemed to work, but something was off in the TSX files and this is where Intellisense was bogged down. Cloning the repo fixed it after trying: clean install, cleaning all VS code folders from the Mac, and running the project in a VS without any plugins failed.
